# MSVC fails to deduce template argument

Tags: c++, c++17

This C++17 code compiles with `clang` and `g++` but MSVC fails to deduce the template argument:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Prop {
  constexpr Prop() {};
};

constexpr const Prop i;

struct Klass {
  template <auto Klass::*MEMBER, const Prop &P,
            std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_pointer_v<decltype(MEMBER)>, bool> = true>
  void def() {}
  void fn();
  int var;
};

void Klass::fn() {}

int main() {
  Klass k;

  k.def<&Klass::fn, i>();
  k.def<&Klass::var, i>();
}
```

Removing only the `std::enable_if` fixes it, as well as removing only the second template argument (the non-type reference). This makes me think that this is a bug. Does anyone see anything that is ill-formed or does anyone have any tips for making it work with MSVC?

I need the `enable_if` because I have multiple similar templates (that are more complex, this is only a minimal repro).

`MSVC 19.37.32822`

Comment: add /permissive- to your compiler options: https://godbolt.org/z/6xdh4c1s5

Comment: Yes, this solves it, thanks
Any explanation?

Comment: No explanation, just noticing that `/permissive-` should have been named `/conformance+` and often solves corner cases

Comment: The documentation may shed some light, or help if you suffer from insomnia. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170

Comment: Just as the GNU compiler has a "non-standard not-quite-C++" mode, Microsoft also has a "non-standard not-quite-C++" mode.  Due to the historical evolution of the Microsoft compiler (which predated C++ standardization), and biasing (by default) towards backwards compatibility.  If I recall correctly, the bias is in the process of switching to be in favor of C++ conformance, with the ability to opt-out of standard conformance and use the Microsoft's non-standard variant C++.

Comment: Also always post complete error along with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program is well-formed and this seems to be a [msvc bug](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Premature-checking-of-template-validity/10491909).

---

[Premature checking of template validity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Premature-checking-of-template-validity/10491909)

> does anyone have any tips for making it work with MSVC?

You can use `/permissive-` flag to make it work with msvc until the bug is fixed. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1MKxnzK7h)

Answer (score 2):

If the template definitions can co-exist (for example if they do not differ only by their default argument values), the best work around is to switch to the alternative form `std::enable_if`:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Prop {
  constexpr Prop() {};
};

constexpr const Prop i;

struct Klass {
  template <auto Klass::*MEMBER, const Prop &P,
          typename=std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_pointer_v<decltype(MEMBER)>>>
  void def() {}
  void fn();
  int var;
};

void Klass::fn() {}

int main() {
  Klass k;

  k.def<&Klass::fn, i>();
  k.def<&Klass::var, i>();
}
```