# MSVC fails to specialize template with `std::enable_if` and a non-type argument

Tags: c++, c++17

This is a follow-up question to [MSVC fails to deduce template argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77437502/msvc-fails-to-deduce-template-argument)

I am unable to find any combination that works on Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (VS 16.11, MSVC 19.29). `clang`, `g++` and MSVC 19.33 and later (without `/permissive-`) compile this code. MSVC 19.29 does not even if using `/permissive-`.

It looks a lot like a SFINAE bug.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

struct Prop1 {
  constexpr Prop1() {};
};
struct Prop2 {
  constexpr Prop2() {};
};

constexpr const Prop1 i;
constexpr const Prop2 j;

// the goal is that def() should have separate implementations
// for member variables and member functions
// (in my real code Prop1/Prop2 have default values, thus the enable_if
// is required, in the minimal repro this is not the case)
struct Klass {
  template <auto Klass::*MEMBER, const Prop2 &P,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_object_pointer_v<decltype(MEMBER)>>>
  void def() {}
  
  template <auto Klass::*MEMBER, const Prop1 &P,
    typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(MEMBER)>>>
  void def() {}
  void fn();
  int var;
};

void Klass::fn() {}

int main() {
  Klass k;

  k.def<&Klass::fn, i>();
  k.def<&Klass::var, j>();
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xE7Y69G3P)

Comment: This is a known msvc bug.

Comment: any ideas for a workaround?

Comment: I am closing this as a dupe. The workaround is given there.

Comment: Btw the program seems to [work here](https://godbolt.org/z/nrvr7oG9q) with all compilers.

Comment: Also always post complete error along with the question.

Comment: VS 2019 (MSVC 19.29) is the one that does not work

Comment: Why are you posting almost same question again and again when you already know that latest version of msvc starts compiling this and so this is a msvc bug?

Comment: I am not posting the same question, the previous one was answered, but this one is a new combination that does not work.

Comment: My point is that msvc has a history of these kinds of bugs. And seeing that other compilers compile this and even latest msvc does, so this implies that it is a bug. Or are you specifically looking only for a workaround?

Comment: Additionally, you've not posted the complete error that you're getting. Always post complete error along with your question.

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a workaround, I don't think there any more special magical command-line options that can make it work.

Comment: Ok so kindly post the complete error that you're getting.

Comment: I've posted a [workaround](https://godbolt.org/z/dcjsE4j44) in my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77698276/12002570).

Comment: I am sure there is some dupes for this. But I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unable to find any combination that works on Visual Studio Enterprise 2019 (VS 16.11, MSVC 19.29)

Here is a **workaround** that uses SFINAE in the return type of the function template. This seems to be a msvc bug.

```
struct Klass {
  template <auto Klass::*MEMBER, const Prop2 &P>
//using SFINAE in the return type 
   typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_object_pointer_v<decltype(MEMBER)>> def() {}
  
  template <auto Klass::*MEMBER, const Prop1 &P>
//using SFINAE in the return type
  typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_member_function_pointer_v<decltype(MEMBER)>> def() {}
  void fn();
  int var;
};
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/58xqhdfKq)